# What is a function that allows character vector creation without using quotation marks?

Tags: r

I remember seeing someone using a function that allowed you to create character vectors where the items were each one word strings as follows (I don't know what the function is called so I'm calling it c_special here):

```
a.random.vector <- c_special(hat, cat, bat)
```

rather than having to do this:

```
a.random.vector <- c("hat", "cat", "bat")
```

It'd be quite useful for me right now as I'm having to manually write out a lot of variable names (~1000) as part of a testing procedure and adding in the quotation marks is not very fun. Does anyone know what the function and package that has this in is or did I dream this up?

Note: I'm sure that this function is highly inefficient but I'm only using it for calling variable names so I'll happily trade that for less typing.

Edit: if I can't track this down I'll probably just use a text macro

Comment: ...hopefully that's the one you were looking for.

Comment: Perfect, exactly the one I was looking for. For anyone else who comes across this, library(Hmisc) followed by Cs("hat", "cat", "bat") works perfectly.

Comment: The [qdap](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qdap/index.html) package has the `qcv` function that does this as well.